# jQuery $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Normally I would be able to figure this one out but this one has me trumped.

I inherited a project at work that is.. horrifying. I've cleaned it all up and everything, except for the javascript/jquery.

I have a simple document ready click alert("test") function running, (and it works??) in an external javascript file. If I include jQuery 1.9.0, the alert pops up twice (which according to the console it is being called somewhere.. so including it where I did seemed to be a duplicate).

So my question is what cases would cause jQuery to work, yet trigger the undefined $?

And .noConflict() is NOT being called.

The code is called here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contactSecondaryYes").click(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be one of two issues, both boiling down to the same issue: **not referencing jQuery**.

You either (I think yours is B):

A) Haven't referenced jQuery 
B) Have another script file (possibly external) that uses jQuery syntax/functions but is referenced **before** your jQuery reference. Simply referencing jQuery first will remedy this issue.

Comment: Bah, I feel stupid for being confused now. The script in question was being included before the header, which was where jquery was defined. I moved it after (didn't work), I moved it to the bottom of the page, and it worked. (Why the difference between after the header not working and the bottom of the page not working?

Comment: @RUJordan There shouldn't be any difference really, I suspect you probably re-tried it, but the JS files/HTML were cached maybe. It's worth trying again after a hard refresh (Ctrl + F5) just to make doublt sure.

Comment: That might have been it, but I'm going to redo this entire mess of code. Scripts are referenced out of place, mix of js/jquery in poorly indented code.. ugg. Thanks for the help

Comment: @RUJordan Ah no problems, good luck with the rest of that project :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use an self-invocing anonymous function for this.

```
(function ($){
  // Use $ here all you want
})(jQuery);
```

What this does is create an anonymous function and call it immediately afterwards, with the jQuery as argument. Within this function, you can use jQuery. There are a lot of variations on this.